# How to send a message from internet to mobile phone in android?

Tags: android

how to create an app to send free message from internet to mobile phone 
like sending a notification to employees , sending back message configuration
, when someone forget her/him password to get her/him password enter the mobile phone number and then getting her/his password  is there any way to do this .

Comment: First you should learn programming, then, when you are experienced enough you could make an app to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GCM - Google Cloud Messaging for Android, http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html.

It allows you to send messages to specified users or your app.

Other solutions: pulling your app server for new information, or using SMS messages.

Comment: parse.com is also a nice and easy to deploy solution. It does not require managing your own server as GCM does, plus it is working on iOS and Windows too.

Comment: @cYrixmorten is it free?

Comment: yep as long as you do not send more than 1 million requests or push messages per month.